# angularjs cookies with latest versions 1.4.1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

**Hello i want to store one sample cookie in my browser and read it.this not working for me**

this is sample html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="KendoDemos">
<head>
   <script src="/home/user/Desktop/kendo/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/home/user/Desktop/kendo/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/home/user/Desktop/kendo/app.js"></script>
 </head>
 <!-- Body tag augmented with ngController directive  -->
 <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h1>Hello</h1>

 </body>
</html>
```

and this my app.js file :

```
 var app = angular.module("KendoDemos", ["ngCookies"]);
 app.controller("MyCtrl",['$scope','$cookies','$cookieStore',MyCtrl]);
 function MyCtrl($scope,$cookies,$cookieStore){
    var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('myFavorite');
    // Setting a cookie
    $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');
    console.log(favoriteCookie);
 }
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have a problem is really logical that your cookie myFavorite isn't set before putting it so you have to switch the instruction of setting and getting.

```
var app = angular.module("KendoDemos", ["ngCookies"]);
 app.controller("MyCtrl",['$scope','$cookies','$cookieStore',MyCtrl]);
 function MyCtrl($scope,$cookies,$cookieStore){
    // Setting a cookie
    $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');
    var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('myFavorite');
    console.log(favoriteCookie);
 }
```

Comment: any one tell me one solution.I checked in browser cookies ,there is no cookie with "myFavorite" name.